# sql logger stuck 'on' in production

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm pretty familiar with grails however my sql logging seems to always be on in production (tomcat6).  It works as expected in development where I can toggle it on and off. I've disabled all logging in my datasource.groovy...

```
dataSource {
    ...
    driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    logSql = false  //<-- still logs sql in production
    properties {
        ...
    }
}
environments {
     production {
            dataSource {
                logSql = false //<-- still logs sql in production
            }
     }
 }
```

and log4j in my config.groovy is pretty simple...

```
log4j = {

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    warn   'org.mortbay.log'
}
```

Finally, I'm building my project using the 'war' command.  Does anyone know where else this could be getting set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to remember having this problem when I first went live with a production war.  I removed the logSql = false from the datasource section and just had it in each environment as needed.  In fact I never put logSql = false - I either remove it completely or comment it out.  I only have logSql = true when needed.

Not sure if that was the root cause or something else, but it fixed it and I haven't had a problem since.

Answer (score 0):

The latest [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging) specify it as 'logSql' , but I've always used 'loggingSql' for as long as i remember.

Also check, http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Hibernate-Sql-Logging-in-Integration-tests-not-working-td3527685.html

Comment: I'll try on our next production build tomorrow night :)

Comment: sry abt that - it wasn't much help. i can only think of externalized configs which may be overwriting the value (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized)

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing... or plugin.  I'll check it out next

Answer (score 0):

Are u externalizing data source properties? If yes, that file may be overriding loggingSql property

I think you should use 'loggingSql" property. we are using it on production. and its working fine (with Grails 2.0 version)

```
dataSource {
    loggingSql=true
}
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            username = "test"
            password = "test"
            loggingSql=true
        }
    }

    production {
        dataSource {
             username = "prod"
            password = "prod"
            loggingSql=false
        }
    }
}
```